# tag merge request -- crop -> cropping

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-naming

These two tags are effectively synonymous, although [crop](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crop) is occasionally also used for [cropped-sensor](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cropped-sensor) or [crop-factor](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crop-factor) questions.

Also, [cropping](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cropping) appears more popular.

So to avoid duplication and ambiguity, [crop](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crop) should be merged into [cropping](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cropping), please.